# How do I fix my Python notebook in Chrome?

Tags: python

I have just downloaded Anaconda navigator as a green, new learner of Python. I clicked on jupyter notebook within the navigator to open Python notebook. It then prompted me to select a browser to open the notebook in in which I selected Chrome. All looked fine, but when I tried to install pip through the !pip install matplotlib command (this is what a class video was instructing me to do as I am just learning for the first time and am very new to this), nothing happened at all. It almost seemed as if the notebook wasn't even "live" or responding to any code. How do I fix this? Again, I am very new to all of this and just getting my feet wet with any type of code language so suggestions/help in the easiest form possible will be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear why you would even need to install matplotlib as it comes with Conda. Also, after running the command, are you able to import the package?

Comment: did you try running sample program

Comment: I highly recommend using terminal for package installation. As correctly pointed out, matplotlib comes by default with the conda installation, so there is no need to install it.

Comment: The video class might be dated as I've noticed even when downloading anaconda, that the version I was trying to download didn't align with the instructor's. I realized I was also just pressing ENTER after the command and not SHIFT+ENTER to run the cell which I found through some digging online that that was how to actually run the cell.

Comment: I'm also not quite sure what the terminal is or how to use it. Not there yet in my learning!

Comment: `matplotlib` comes with *the Anaconda distribution*. `conda` is a package/environment manager, which can come independant from Anaconda.

Comment: Honestly, learning to program through Jupyter notebooks is not great. Learning what the terminal is and how to use it should be *the first thing you learn* when you do a "hello world".

Comment: Any suggestions on the best resources or places to learn Python for a first timer?